# How to use pandas beyond the pd.Timestamp.min and pd.Timestamp.max value?

Tags: python, pandas

```
pd.Timestamp.min
pd.Timestamp.max

Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145224193')
Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
```

I found out that pandas has a min and max date value.  If I need to have date beyond these values, is that possible ?

Is it not possible to move the min/max values, like a century window ?
Any alternatives without pandas then ?

Thanks very much.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-oob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known limitation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations) due to the nanosecond precision of Timestamps.

> #### Timestamp limitations
>
> Since pandas represents timestamps in nanosecond resolution, the time
> span that can be represented using a 64-bit integer is limited to
> approximately 584 years

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans) suggests to use [`pandas.period_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html):

> #### Representing out-of-bounds span
>
> If you have data that is outside of the Timestamp bounds, see
> [Timestamp limitations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-timestamp-limits), then you can use a PeriodIndex and/or Series of
> Periods to do computations.

```
pd.period_range("1215-01-01", "1381-01-01", freq="D")

PeriodIndex(['1215-01-01', '1215-01-02', '1215-01-03', '1215-01-04',
             '1215-01-05', '1215-01-06', '1215-01-07', '1215-01-08',
             '1215-01-09', '1215-01-10',
             ...
             '1380-12-23', '1380-12-24', '1380-12-25', '1380-12-26',
             '1380-12-27', '1380-12-28', '1380-12-29', '1380-12-30',
             '1380-12-31', '1381-01-01'],
            dtype='period[D]', length=60632)
```

##### converting a Series

there is no direct method (like `to_period`) to convert an exiting Series, you need to go through a `PeriodIndex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'str': ['1900-01-01', '2500-01-01']})
df['period'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['str'], freq='D').values
```

output:

```
print(df)
          str      period
0  1900-01-01  1900-01-01
1  2500-01-01  2500-01-01

print(df.dtypes)
str          object
period    period[D]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was hoping that they could make it easier, like a shifting window of 584 years.  I guess may be enhancement to pandas.

Comment: does it mean that i can still have a DataFrame with index outside the valid range ?

Comment: If you use periods, yes